# Internet Explorer receives 403 Error when viewing dev environment SSL test certificate (using MAMP)

Tags: apache, https, internet-explorer, mamp

I've been developing a site with MAMP which has a handy way of generating (obviously) unverified SSL certificates for testing purposes.

All was well when testing with Chrome, Firefox, Safari you simply have to acknowledge the suspicious certificate once per session and that's that.

When I fire up (in Parallels since I'm on a Mac) to test Internet Explorer I get the same warning about the certificate but I hit "yeah ok, let's do this" and the server returns a 403 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog explains what's happening](http://coding-journal.com/enabling-https-in-apache-results-in-403-forbidden-in-internet-explorer/#comment-94024):

> After enabling HTTPS for a certain VHOST (within MAMP, but that is
>   probably not relevant), Internet Explorer 8 started denying to display
>   any HTTPS enabled page, showing a 403 Forbidden error instead. This
>   problem occurred because of the following setting in my Apache
>   configuration…

In your Apache SSL config — MAMP stores as a user template, go to `File > Edit Template > Apache > httpd-ssl.conf` and find the `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck` directive (or simply add it) and set it's value to `off`:

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
```

Now IE should be good to go with the rest of the browser gang.